# Android: getting the time

Tags: android, time, clock

i am currently using the following line to achieve the time: System.currentTimeInMilis.
I have noticed it doesn't consider time zones,or does it not match the android phone it self by the time, while on the emulator it does match.s
so is there another type of way to get the android clock it self? so when the user adjusts he's phones built in clock, it affects it too?

```
float getTime()
    {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

Comment: What time format are you looking for?

Comment: any format of which i can extract the hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [currentTimeMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). It *has* a time zone, which happens to be UTC (which is the default for Unix time stamps).

If you want to convert it to a different time zone you can make use of the Java Calendar and TimeZone classes:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Alternatively you can just create a new GregorianCalendar instance. By default its TimeZone will match the local one (as set on the device) and the time will be set to "now".

There are also other ways for retrieving the current time according the current time zone and locale as string. Take a look at [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html).

**EDIT Explaining the usage of Calendar**

Read the documentation for Calendar.getTimeMillis(). That method returns the Unix time stamp again which happens to have the time zone UTC.

You have to use the Calendar.get() method instead for getting the correct values. See following example for getting the current hour in the correct time zone via your calendar object:

```
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_HAY);
```

Read the documentation of Calendar. There are plenty of fields like HOUR_OF_DAY which help you getting values like the year, month, minute, seconds etc.

Comment: Can you do two things: Check the time zone setting and current time on your phone and post the lines of code you were trying to use?

Comment: my timezone on my phone is set to israel gmt + 3, which is 3 hours + for the time i get.. so what i get on my phone is running 3 hours late for me.. and i'll add the code lines.

Comment: here it is, the problem should be here because other than that all works perfectly fine, checked 100 times.

Comment: @DanielMendel I updated my answer. If you're having more questions about examples then don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I see, It works now thanks, but is there like another way of getting the time in one float, just like System.currentTimeMillis? i kinda hate the idea of using calendars and importing all these features for such a simple task (i like keeping my stuff as simple and short as possible)

Comment: Well, it's just a matter of maths and conventions you're applying. In the whole vast computing world the convention of the Unix time stamp is used and by definition its time zone is UTC. If you want to have a different convention you need to add / subtract the amount of milliseconds for shifting the Unix time stamp to your own time zone. I wouldn't do that, because you have to take daylight savings into account which largely vary all over the world. The TimeZone class helps you with that, however. TimeZone.getOffset gives you the time difference between your timezone and UTC for any given date